Arithmetic Progressions involving 3 distinct terms
I've been trying to find the number of Arithmetic Progressions involving 3 distinct terms of the set:
$ \sum_{i=0}^{2021} a_i \cdot 3^i, \quad \text{where } a_i \in \{0, 2\}$
But I've had no sucess, firstly because the I'm not sure how to state the problem of counting in mathematical terms to be able to continue, this is, the problem is to view arithmetical progressions given by numbers in base 3.

Hint: List out the first few such terms, and then slowly come to the realization that there doesn't seem to be any such AP. Then, figure out how to prove that.

Work through the following. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and what you can't push through.
Let $A, B$ be two such distinct numbers of the set. Show that $\frac{A+B}{2}$:

Is an integer
In base 3, the right-most non-zero digit is 1.

Hence, conclude that there are no 3-term AP from this set.

Good, I think it could be good to give a ful proof of it.

@JoãoVíctorMelo I encourage you to post your full proof.
